# latex error Missing \endcsname inserted. \protect l.49 \newlabel{\mathbb {F}}{{1.2.30}{18}}

Tags: labels

I am getting a latex error during thesis writing with the following message.

```
LaTeX Warning: Label `' multiply defined.

! Missing \endcsname inserted. \protect l.49 \newlabel{\mathbb {F}}{{1.2.30}{18}}

?
```

can someone please help what it is about and how to remove it?

Answer (score 1):

You have `\label{\mathbf{F}}` somewhere in your document which is wrong, you should just have simple letters and numbers in `\label` never formatting. `\label` is unrelated to anything printed in the document it is just an internal identifier for cross referencing.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I just tried it and removed. I have nowhere this label now in the document but still getting the error.

Comment: delete the `.aux` file which has been corrupted by the earlier error, latex will make a new one without the problem.

Comment: yesss. got the problem solved. Thank you very much.

Comment: Would you please give some remark about how it worked?

Comment: the error that you show is `l.49...` which was line 49 of the aux file, that is input at the start of each run so if you corrupt it then you sometimes need to delete it to allow latex to get past that point.